# Why am I getting "You are not administrator of any billing account" error on GCP when trying to create a new VM Instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

### Background

I'm new to GCP. I once had setup a Google Maps Billing account to access the Google Maps API for one of my projects. Because I signed up through Google Maps Billing I wasn't initially given the signup credit of 300$. I contacted the billing support and they credited the 300$ to my Google Maps Billing Account.

### Issue

When I tried to create a VM Instance in my project which is connected to the Maps billing account, it shows the following.
[Screenshot showing my account doesn't have administrative right over any billing account][1]

Screenshot[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zWhX.jpg

The given project is connected to my Maps billing and I was informed that Maps Billing should work for GCP Services.

What am I missing? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Google Maps Billing is not the same as Google Cloud Billing. You must set up separate billing accounts. You can use the same Payments account.

Comment: I want to use google credits alloted to me. Which is in my Maps Billing Account. Credits can't be transferred to different account. I was told by GCP team that Maps Billing should work for Google Cloud Platform Services. Also the particular error that I'm getting states that I don't have Administrative Privileges over the Billing Account, which I have.

Comment: Google Cloud Platform does not use Google Maps billing accounts. Open a billing support ticket, which is free.